# $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ with $A^8=I$, then what can we tell about the degree of its minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions, minimal-polynomials

$A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ with $A^8=I$, then what can we tell about the degree of its minimal polynomial?

> > What I understand that $A$ satisfies $x^8-1=0$, and as we know characteristic polynomial of $A$ is 3rd degree so   characteristic polynomial is either $(x^2+1)(x+1)=0$ or$(x^2+1)(x-1)=0$

But I can not say anything about its minimal polynomial. Please help.

Comment: what about if $A=I$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $t-1$

Comment: $x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)$, so we have other degree $3$ polynomials like $(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there uncountably many $A\in M_3 (\mathbb {R})$ such that $A^8=I $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823784/are-there-uncountably-many-a-in-m-3-mathbb-r-such-that-a8-i)

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I think the proposed duplicate only makes a passing remark about possible minimal polynomials for this case.  That Question was a multiple choice kind of exercise, and I don't see how any of the Answers there give an exhaustive response on the minimal polynomial.  I will look again.

Comment: @hardmath We can easily read off the minimal polynomials of the (uncountably many) solutions to $A^8=I$ and together with Cayley-Hamilton this is already quite a lot. But yes, it is perhaps not an exact duplicate. It should be helpful as a hint, though.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Reference:

[Minimal polynomials and characteristic polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262334/minimal-polynomials-and-characteristic-polynomials)

Answer for $A\in  M_3 (\mathbb {R})$ satisfying $A^8=I$:

[Are there uncountably many $A\in M_3 (\mathbb {R})$ such that $A^8=I $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823784/are-there-uncountably-many-a-such-that-a8-i)

Answer (score 0):

As asked about matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ satisfying $A^8=I$, "what can we tell about the degree of its minimal polynomial?" , the answer is that the degree of the minimal polynomial can be $1,2,$ or $3$.  We show a bit more, roughly what minimal polynomials of $A$ are possible.

Since $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ and the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial (of degree $3$), the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most $3$.  The minimal polynomial must divide $x^8 - 1$, since $A^8 = I$, and therefore the minimal polynomial also has *no repeated roots*.

It remains only to show that degrees $1,2,$ and $3$ can each be achieved.  The case of degree $1$ requires a single eigenvalue (root of characteristic polynomial) of geometric multiplicity $3$, so take $A=I$ or $A=-I$.

The case of degree $2$ requires two distinct eigenvalues, one of geometric multiplicity $2$ and one of multiplicity $1$.  For example:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Finally we consider the case of minimal polynomial having degree $3$.  Recall that the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of a polynomial has characteristic polynomial equal to its minimal polynomial.  Therefore any degree $3$ real polynomial dividing $x^8 - 1$ can be realized as the minimal polynomial of matrix $A$.  From its real irreducible factors, as @Qurultay commented:

$$ x^8 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^2-\sqrt 2 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt 2 x+1) $$

Thus we can choose either of its degree $1$ irreducible factors and any one of its three degree $2$ irreducible factors.  Multiplying those two choices gives us a degree $3$ divisor of $x^8 - 1$, and that can be realized as the minimal polynomial (and characteristic polynomial) of $A$.  For example, $(x+1)(x^2 + 1) = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ and:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$